# CodeIgniter shared data between calls to load->view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Consider a view called render_thing, which I load from a controller like so:

```
$html = $this->load->view(
  'render_thing',                   
  array(
    'someParam' => $globalParam
    'permissionMode' => 'guest'
  ),
  true
);
log($html);
```

Later on in that same controller, I load the view again, except I don't override the optional permissionMode parameter. I'm assume that in the view code, `$permissionMode` would be `unset`.

```
$moreHtml = $this->load->view(
  'render_thing',                   
  array(
    'someParam' => 'blablabla'
  ),
  true
);
```

However, in the render_thing view code, on the second call, `$permissionMode` is still `'guest'`. Can you tell me what is going on here?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Loader.php, `Loader::_ci_load` in the CodeIgniter source...

```
    /*
     * Extract and cache variables
     *
     * You can either set variables using the dedicated $this->load_vars()
     * function or via the second parameter of this function. We'll merge
     * the two types and cache them so that views that are embedded within
     * other views can have access to these variables.
     */
    if (is_array($_ci_vars))
    {
        $this->_ci_cached_vars = array_merge($this->_ci_cached_vars, $_ci_vars);
    }
    extract($this->_ci_cached_vars);
```

So, this would be why the parameter is still set. `load_vars` is not a method, but `vars` is; problem is that it doesn't provide a facility to erase the cache. Therefore, since CodeIgniter is still PHP4 compatible, you may always do this: `$this->load->_ci_cached_vars = array();`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and figured out the problem in Loader.php as follows;

```
/*
* Extract and cache variables
*
* You can either set variables using the dedicated $this->load_vars()
* function or via the second parameter of this function. We'll merge
* the two types and cache them so that views that are embedded within
* other views can have access to these variables.
*/
if (is_array($_ci_vars))
{
    $this->_ci_cached_vars = array_merge($this->_ci_cached_vars, $_ci_vars);
}else{
    $this->load->_ci_cached_vars = array();
}
extract($this->_ci_cached_vars);
```