# Template plugin in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i've been using and studying Collin Williams template plugin (http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html#manipulation) and i've already posted this issue on CI's forum but i think the last post was last year maybe its not being monitored by Colllin or wat but i guess i'll just have to post this here maybe you guys can help.

Original Post on CI Forum

> Hello Collin,
>
> ```
> I’ve been studying your template plugin lately, as i was following your guide, 
> i came across this line of code
>
> $data = array('name' => 'John Smith', 'birthdate' => '11/15/1950'); 
> $this->template->write_view('content', 'user/profile', $data, TRUE);
> ```
>
> it was a bit confusing whether in the view files, like
>   mymastertemplate.php for example, how do i accessthe $data array, does
>   it have to be $content defined by that first param. a region, or by
>   $name and $birthdate? ... cuz’ it says there $content will display the
>   data array? its a bit confusing. Hope you could enlighten me.

Basically thats my problem.

Answer (score 0):

On `Template.php` library we can see function `write_view()`. Now, focus on `$data = NULL`. Now then finds a file of existed data on APPPATH.'views/'.$suggestion.'.php' so I think that `$args[0]` should be a file which is loaded and break it, than loaded a view template on `$data`.

```
function write_view($region, $view, $data = NULL, $overwrite = FALSE)
   {
      $args = func_get_args();

      // Get rid of non-views
      unset($args[0], $args[2], $args[3]);

      // Do we have more view suggestions?
      if (count($args) > 1)
      {
     foreach ($args as $suggestion)
     {
        if (file_exists(APPPATH .'views/'. $suggestion . EXT) or file_exists(APPPATH .'views/'. $suggestion))
        {
           // Just change the $view arg so the rest of our method works as normal
           $view = $suggestion;
           break;
        }
     }
      }

      $content = $this->CI->load->view($view, $data, TRUE);
      $this->write($region, $content, $overwrite);

   }
```

In another way, `$data` should be as array which will response for View template data on Codeigniter library (standard view of CI: `$this->CI->load->view(...)`)

```
$data = array('name' => 'John Smith', 'birthdate' => '11/15/1950'); 
$this->template->write_view('content', 'user/profile', $data, TRUE);
```

On template file '/user/profile.php' use as example:

HTML/PHP template file `profile.php`:

```
Your name: <?php echo $data["name"]; ?>
Your name: <?php echo $data["birthdate"]; ?>
```

And as I see, a CONTENT var must be an ARRAY due to documentation...

```
$template['default']['regions'] = array(
  'header' => array(
    'content' => array('<h1>Welcome</h1>','<p>Hello World</p>'), ### <----- AS EXAMPLE
    'name' => 'Page Header',
    'wrapper' => '<div>',
    'attributes' => array('id' => 'header', 'class' => 'clearfix')
  )
);
```

Regions must be defined as template, so if you didn't have `header` region that didn't work:

```
$template['default']['regions'] = array(
  'header',
  'content',
  'footer',
);
```

!!!!!
Simply, he can't acces private access variable `_ci_cached_vars` which is stored data like `$name`. RELATED TOPIC: [CodeIgniter shared data between calls to load->view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098636/codeigniter-shared-data-between-calls-to-load-view)

Comment: so basically it isn't on the $content region? i really don't get what you mean but according to the user guide on his website it says "/* Template loads the views/user/profile.php view with the $data array passed in
and writes the result to the $content region, overwriting any previous content in the region */"

Comment: Yes, but before you add on template a region should be defined in $template array.

Comment: i've already done the neccesarry configs, but i was confused when i tried displaying the data on $data array using $content on views/template.php it says there that it doesn't exist but when i ttried accessing it using $name and $birthdate its fine

Comment: Put in view template `var_dump($GLOBALS)`. I'm think that variables is missing or you are not pointed good to an array.

Comment: what excatly do i need to find in $GLOBALS?

Comment: If you miss $name this is because it isn't in var `$region`. Function `write()` finds `$region` and if `$region` is in main conf var exists than will put new an array or FALSE on overwrite. Due to it can be onl y SINGLE MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY. Look at code ` function write($region, $content, $overwrite = FALSE)
    {
       if (isset($this->regions[$region]))
       {
   if ($overwrite === TRUE) // Should we append the content or overwrite it
   {
      $this->regions[$region]['content'] = array($content);
   } else {
      $this->regions[$region]['content'][] = $content;
   }
       }`

Comment: what excatly do i need to find in $GLOBALS? <-- find missed variables that can't you find.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25029/discussion-between-lemoncodes-and-marin-sagovac)